# How to call function from another class in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a function in my questionsscreen.dart file and the code of that function are: -

```
onQuestionAnswered(bool answerStatus) {
    setState(() {
      isAnswerSelected = true;

      scoreTrackerIcons.add(answerStatus
          ? const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
          : const Icon(
              Icons.clear,
              color: Colors.red,
            ));

      if (indexOfQuestion + 1 == questionsDataInstance.questions.length) {
        isQuizEnded = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Now i have InkWell in another file answer.dart whose code is : -

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: answerBackgroundColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Center(
              child: Text(answerText,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I want to use onQuestionAnswered function with InkWell onTap. How can I do this?

Comment: do you have any true false value to pass in this function??

Comment: yes this function will have a arugment of tru or false

Comment: from where do you get true or false in onTap??

Comment: answerStatus will have a true or false value

Comment: onTap(){  onQuestionAnswered(true); }

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **callbacks concept** , make the second file take an argument of function with the same signature of your *onQuestionAnswered(bool answerStatus)* ex:

```
final Function(bool) onQuestionAnswered ;
```

and just on InkWell tap call the passed function ex:

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onQuestionAnswered.call(answerStatus) ;
     },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: answerBackgroundColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Center(
              child: Text(answerText,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ),
      )
```